# Conditionally push to 1 of 2 arrays in Perl

Tags: perl

Is there a better way to do this? I'm trying to build 2 arrays based on the value of a scalar:

```
my (@x, @y);
my $r = [$v1, $v2, $v3];
push @x, $r if $s eq 'YES';
push @y, $r if $s ne 'YES';
```

I tried using:

```
push $s eq 'YES' ? @x : @y, $r;
```

with and without parens, but no go.

Error is:

```
Type of arg 1 to push must be array (not null operation) at comp_report.pl line 79, near "$r;"
```

Comment: I think your code is right as_is. I think that using a *ternary operator* for something else than assigning a variable is a bad habit (what's can be done with Perl *ternary operator* sometimes cannot be reproduced in other languages implementing it)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

push requires its first parameter to be an actual array (at least before perl 5.14 and earlier - it may have changed), not an expression, so you need to:

```
push @{ $s eq 'YES' ? \@x : \@y}, $r;
```

Beginning in 5.14, builtins such as push [experimentally can take arbitrary hard references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html#Array-and-hash-container-functions-accept-references), so this works:

```
push $s eq 'YES' ? \@x : \@y, $r;
```

Comment: +1 Just a few seconds earlier than the same answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14446203/1337398). :)

Answer (score 9):

```
push @{ $s eq 'YES' ? \@x : \@y }, $r;
```

`push` really wants to get an array as its first argument, but you can still select the target dynamically by using references.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred solution would be

```
if($s eq 'YES'){
   push @x, $r; 
else{
    push @y, $r;
}
```

Just a style thing. Using a ternary expression as the first argument to push looks messy to me, and I don't mind the extra lines. Personal taste I guess!

Comment: Without getting too deep into it, having control over your "l-values" as well as your "r-values" is something I expect in a dynamic language. It's a common idiom in Lisp, for example. I was surprised Perl was fighting me on this, and really wanted to know if it was possible.